# Finding length of a string

Tags: c, string

1. I have written a code for length of a string.
2. This gets compiled successfully buy there is some problem at the 
   output.
3. My output gets stuck after i enter the string.
4. i have to find the length using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int leng(char*);
void main()
{
    char str[20];
    scanf("%s",str);
    printf("%s",str);
    int l;
    l=leng(str);
    printf("%d",l);
}

int leng(char*p)
{
    int l=0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: The loop in `leng()` tests the value of `*p`, but never changes `p` or `*p`.   It is therefore an infinite loop.

Comment: ..something that would have been obvious if you has used you debugger, of even just printed out a few important vars each time round:(   Please write no more code until you can use your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, problem is here

```
while(*p!='\0')
```

Here pointer `*p` does not incremented. so, while loop working infinitely and may be program crashed.

So, use

```
while(*p++!='\0')
```

instead of

```
while(*p!='\0')
```

Comment: Consider editing to p+=sizeof(char) since ++ only works for architectures where char is byte sized.

Comment: ohh..that was such a silly mistake. thanks alot rsp for helping.

Comment: @CaioSym: sizeof(char) is by definition always 1, so that is not a concern. Also, the ++ operator takes size into account, so it works for all data types, regardless of size.

Comment: Interesting. I could swear it could be mapped to two bytes in some cases... Good point about the ++. I had forgotten that it took size into consideration.

Comment: @CaioSym That's bad advice. A pointer always increments by the size of the thing it is pointing to.

Comment: @CaioSym: char can be any size, meausered in bits or bytes, but sizeof char is always 1 in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int leng(char*);
int main()
 {
  char str[20];
  scanf("%s",str);
  printf("%s", "Length of input string is ");
  int l;
  l=leng(str);
  printf("%d",l);
    }

int leng(char*p)
{
int l=0;
while(*p!='\0')
{
    l++;
    p = p +1;
}
return l;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1st error- You have not used '&' inside scanf. 
2nd error- You need to put p++ after l++ inside the while loop.

Comment: It is ok. & not used in scanf function while reading a string.

Comment: Ok. It is working without &. But why is it not necessary in strings like in integers?

Comment: @Shashwat: In most contexts in C, arrays are converted to a pointer to the first elemenet.